# custom validation class only testing last element

Tags: php, associative-array

I have been trying to make a custom validation class, but it is bothering me that it only is test thing last element it sees. I need it to test everything I put into it.

```
<?php

class Valid {

function validate(array $args){

    $errors = NULL;

    //********************************
    //Find each key validation.
    //********************************
    foreach ($args as $key => $value){


        //*********************************
        //Check for letters only, a-z, A-Z.
        //*********************************
        if ($key == 'letters'){

            $letters = preg_match('/^\pL+$/u', $value) ? TRUE : FALSE;
            $letters_value = $value;
            $letters_array[] = $letters;

        }

        //*********************************
        //Check for numbers only, 0-9.
        //*********************************
        if ($key == 'numbers'){

            $numbers = preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $value) ? TRUE : FALSE;
            $numbers_value = $value;
            $numbers_array[] = $numbers;

        }

        //*********************************
        //Check for vaild email address.
        //*********************************
        if ($key == 'email'){

            $email = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? TRUE : FALSE;
            $email_value = $value;
            $email_array[] = $email;

        }

        //*********************************
        //Check for empty string.
        //*********************************
        if ($key == 'empty'){

            $empty_it = (trim($value) == FALSE) ? TRUE : FALSE;
            $empty_array[] = $empty_it;

        }


    }

    //********************************
    //Check if you failed letters only.
    //********************************
    if ( count($letters_array) != count(array_filter($letters_array)) ) $errors .= 'You can only enter letters a-z or A-Z.<br />';


    //********************************
    //Check if you failed numbers only.
    //********************************
    if ( count($numbers_array) != count(array_filter($numbers_array)) ) $errors .= 'You can only enter numbers 0-9.<br />';


    //*************************************
    //Check if you failed email validation.
    //*************************************
    if ( count($email_array) != count(array_filter($email_array)) ) $errors .= 'You must enter a vaild e-mail address.<br />';


    //*************************************
    //Check if you empty string.
    //*************************************
    if ( count($empty_array) != count(array_filter($empty_array)) ) $errors .= 'You must enter a value for each required field.<br />';



    //********************
    //Display the errors.
    //********************
    if ($errors) echo '<h3>Oops..</h3>'. $errors; var_dump($args); die;

}

}
```

And then I call it like this:

```
$Validate->validate( array('empty' => $display_name, 'empty' => $password, 'empty' => $password_again, 
'empty' => $gender, 'empty' => $month, 'empty' => $day, 'empty' => $year, 'email' => $email, 'letters' => $gender,
'numbers' => $month, 'numbers' => $day, 'numbers' => $year) );
```

But my result is this:

```
array(4) { ["empty"]=> string(4) "2013" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["letters"]=> string(0) "" ["numbers"]=> string(4) "2013" }
```

Any help?

Comment: Note that at `if ($errors) echo '<h3>Oops..</h3>'. $errors; var_dump($args); die;` 2nd and 3rd statment (`var_dump` and `die`) are always executed because you didn't wrap them in curly brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reuse keys in arrays. The last key - value pair will overwrite all the previous.

Write an array like:

```
$Validate->validate(array(
    'empty' => array($display_name, $password, $password_again, $gender, $month, $day, $year, $email),
    'letters' => array($gender, $month),
    'numbers' => array($day, $year).
));
```

and parse it appropriately:

```
if (isset($args["key"])) {
     foreach ($args["key"] as $value) {
         // ...
     }
}
// and this for every method to check
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array('empty' => $display_name, 'empty' => $password, 'empty' => $password_again, 
'empty' => $gender, 'empty' => $month, 'empty' => $day, 'empty' => $year, 'email' => $email, 'letters' => $gender,
'numbers' => $month, 'numbers' => $day, 'numbers' => $year)
```

This is not a valid hash. Keys must be unique.

You could, however, pass something like this:

```
array(
array('empty' => $display_name),
array('empty' => $password),
array('empty' => $password_again),
array('empty' => $gender), ...
)
```

and modify your loop appropriately.

**Documentation**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.